# Why does including windows.h create syntax errors, preventing instantiation of a class? (C2146, C2065)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

*(Platform details: Windows 10, Visual Studio C++ (MSVC 14.26.28801))*

Here's a basic repro. Consider the following program that works fine:

```cpp
struct Rectangle {};

int main() {
    Rectangle rect {};
}
```

Compiles and runs as expected.

But now if we introduce the import to windows.h like this:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

struct Rectangle {};

int main() {
    Rectangle rect {};
}
```

We get the following compile errors:

- `syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'rect' (C2146) [25, 5]`
- `'rect': undeclared identifier (C2065) [25, 5]`
- `expected a ';' [25, 15]`
- `'rect': undeclared identifier (C2065) [26, 5]`
- `identifier "rect" is undefined [26, 32]`
- `function call missing argument list (C4551) [25, 5]`

Yikes!

Microsoft's docs aren't shedding much insight:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2146?view=vs-2019

(I'm still new to c++, apologies if this is something obvious)

I'm assuming there's some sort of...directive somewhere in windows.h that changes some sort of behavior, but I'm not really sure what to search for or look for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derp okay, found the answer.

I was using `Rectangle` as a "hello world" example.

Turns out windows.h already includes a "Rectangle", meaning the symbols collide

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle)

The implicit "everything from windows.h is available in the global namespace now!" caught me off guard.

(Switching my class name to "Marks_Rectangle" fixes the problem!)

Comment: [Rectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle) is a function, not a class. There aren't any classes in the Windows API (outside of window classes, but those aren't your C++ classes).

Comment: FWIW, you also have the option of `MarksNamespace::Rectangle` if you want instead.

Comment: That's not a *"namespace clash"*. It's *"symbols"* that collide. And of course, the entirety of the Windows API lives in the global namespace. It's C, after all (with GDI+ being the odd one out, but that's really a library on top of the flat GDI+ API).

Comment: thanks all for the pointers! super appreciate it! updated the answer for correctness.

Comment: Sorry, it's not *"symbols"*, but *"identifiers"*. *"symbols"* is what the linker sees, not the compiler.

Comment: You could also feel free to [accept your own answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).